# How to get socket exception value

Tags: c#, socketexception

I used a component for creating socket connection. Now, I have a client and server that can connect to each other by the component. but my problem is it: When some error happening, I got a msg like this:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I want to know is any relation between this code (0x80004005) and Winsock Error Codes in 
[MSDN WebSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924071.aspx) ? what is this code mean? is it display the value error code?! or something like this?

actually I want to get the related value like `10061` but I dont know how I can get it by above string value. Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ErrorCode property of the exception object contains the socket error code. The list of error codes are defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx).

The error in your case is **WSAECONNREFUSED 10061**

BTW, you have to catch the SocketException and not the general Exception to get the error code.

```
try
{
}
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException sockEx)
{
int errorCode = sockEx.ErrorCode;
}
```

If, however, you want to get the native error code, you can use `sockEx.NativeErrorCode` instead.

Comment: I know that. but I want to know is there any way that I understand the error Code like 10061 by this : 0x80004005?? I have some other that I want to know their error code, not specially in this case.

Comment: The error code 10061 should be present in the ErrorCode property. There is no need to 'match' the error code in the string (0x80004005) to the actual error code (10061); it is already there in the property.

Comment: Also, the link you provided is for Windows Mobile 6.5

Comment: Thanks for answer but I used a component that give me just above string that I said in question. I dont have any other property.

Comment: So you are saying you are unable to catch the exception yourself and that only the error string is returned to you? If so, there is no elegant way to do this. The underlying component might return 0x80004005 for multiple errors. The only way to know that the error was a 'connection refused' error is through the actual error code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not able to catch the exception? How is the error string returned to you?

Comment: So you say I can just know error code by its description?! there are about 50 errors or more!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57803/discussion-between-elahe-and-bobby-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

If you structure your code to catch a C# exception, then the exception should have the error text.

EXAMPLE:

```
  try 
  {
     ...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
    MessaageBox.show(ex.toString());
  }
```

Failing all else, you can always PInvoke the old Win32 [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/getting-winsock-error-messages-in-string-format/

And there's always sockets.com (from my 16-bit WinSock2 programming days):

- http://www.sockets.com/err_lst1.htm#ErrorsInNumericOrder

Comment: so this code (0x80004005) is not unique? and I cant get exception value from this?

Comment: If you were programming the socket directly, you could catch the exception and read the error message and/or error number directly from the exception.  If you're using a third-party component, it sounds like the component is just returning a generic "0x80004005: Operation failed" error.  The component is masking the original error.

Comment: Here's a list of common HRESULT errors (including 0x80004005): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx